# How to declare a void-returning function and variadic auto-typed parameters?

Tags: c++, webassembly

Right now I have something like this:

```cpp
extern ... {
   void foo(int i);
};
```

I need something more like:

```cpp
extern ... {
   void foo(auto ...bar);
};
```

But that isn't allowed by the language, as C++ denies `auto` in function declarations.

If I'm not mistaken, a `<template>` would create a whole new function per call, depending on the arguments that it was called with, correct me if I'm wrong.

**Restrictions**: I may not, in any way whatsoever, define the function here, as I have **absolutely no control** over the function, no header, nothing.

If I could, I would've used a lambda or template.

If you're thinking that this is an X Y problem, which it might still be, I'm doing this while compiling C++ to WebAssembly.

---

If you care to know, the *actual* code looks like:

```cpp
#define WASM_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default"))) \
    extern "C"

#define WASM_IMPORT extern “C”

WASM_EXPORT const void log(int output);
```

Key point: the actual extern functions are ***not*** available at compile time.

As the actual code I'm using isn't mine, I'll give proper credit to the actual author: https://medium.com/@dougschaefer/going-straight-to-clang-for-webassembly-928df1484430

Their short tutorial on WebAssembly using C++ is what I'm using. Their implementation of the generated output file is there too, if you need more information.

For those of you who do not know, JavaScript's `log()` function is very similar to C's `int printf(char*, ...)`, it even has a format string.

Comment: From reading the spec I have the idea that WebAssembly functions can only have [one specific vector](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/types.html#result-types) of argument types. So you will need to know the argument types up front.

Comment: It's not a Web Assembly function, it's calling from the JavaScript environment.

If it matters, I'm using clang-8.

Comment: So you're declaring the type of a variadic JavaScript function that will be provided by the runtime? As I said, WebAssembly doesn't support variadic functions at the moment. So at least the [Rust interop](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-js-imports/variadic.html) and [Go interop](https://medium.zenika.com/go-1-11-webassembly-for-the-gophers-ae4bb8b1ee03) represent variadic functions as taking an array of some type.

Comment: I've updated the post more, but do you want to see the Node JavaScript too?

Comment: More information would certainly help me or other people help you.

Comment: Template and auto parameters are basically the same thing, auto parameters are just shorter syntax

Comment: If it has to be `extern "C"`, you're restricted to C types. No templates. "Best" you can get is a C variadic function declaration which is not fun to deal with doing interop. (And you can't "instantiate" a function. You can instantiate templates, or define functions.)

Comment: Dobn't write that the title is misleading and the question weird. Change that.

Comment: Also, WebAssembly's return types can be vectors, but the parameters is not a vector, that is probably there for a simple explanation. Well I guess, but it's complicated stuff you don't need to worry about, this is intended to be primarily a C++ question.

Comment: @Mat Sorry for the incorrectly written question, I'll fix it right now.

Comment: @Yunnosch Okay, I'll rename it.

Comment: I'm surprised this question gets -2 and no upvotes. Hey readers, let's change it a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Figured it out

Funnily enough, I already wrote the answer in the question, without realizing it.

Since you're limited to the types available in `C`, you can use simple `C` variardic function parameters.

You compared it to `printf`; `printf`'s declaration would look like this:

```c
extern "C" int printf(const char* const, ...);
```

Yeah, that's it. The `...` tells the compiler that it can accept anything past that point, and that a single function will handle it all.

**Warning**: C's variardic parameters aren't type safe, but with JavaScript it won't matter anyways.

Thank you @Mat for your comment, which reminded me that `C` has variardic parameters.

Also, I worked with them a long time ago, so I guess I'd just forgotten them since.

---

Sorry for any misinterpretations caused by my poor wording:
The `extern` functions are being ported from the local envirnment, which in this case is JavaScript.

The function is **already** a vararg function.

Better yet, since you need even the first argument to be of a variable type, you can directly use `(...)`.

## Update

Actually, `extern "C"` isn't your only option, `extern "C++"` is also an option, allowing C++ types, while still preventing name mangling.